# Can't replicate photos app context menu to drag transition in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm struggling to replicate the smooth transition the Photos app has from an Image's context menu to dragging using SwiftUI (I can't even find a way to programatically close the context menu)
[Desired effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvVKu.gif)

Here's my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var positionDelta = CGSize.zero

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .foregroundColor(.mint)
                .frame(width: 50)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .global)
                        .onChanged { gesture in
                            positionDelta = gesture.translation
                        }
                        .onEnded { _ in
                            withAnimation {
                                positionDelta = CGSize.zero
                            }
                        }
                )
                .contextMenu(menuItems: {
                    Text("Menu Item 1")
                    Text("Menu Item 2")
                    Text("Menu Item 3")
                }
                )
                .position(CGPoint(x: 175 + positionDelta.width, y: 175 + positionDelta.height))
        }
        .frame(width: 350, height: 350)
        .background(.primary)
        .cornerRadius(10.0)
    }
}
```

Looked on google, read several posts and read the docs for contextMenu